# Curved Bottom Navigation

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Я делаю меню по [этому видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g27dEyx-zYU).И проект на [Гитхаб](https://github.com/sharathbabugv/BottomAppBar). Все получилось но только не могу разобраться как три точки всплывающее меню сделать первым а за ним шло все остальное. Можете увидеть это на фото то как сейчас[image: сейчас]

Comment: вряд ли кто то будет смотреть "это видео". вопрос должен содержать воспроизводимый пример проблемы прямо в вопросе (код, разметка и т.д), а не какое то видео ..

Comment: @pavlofff https://github.com/sharathbabugv/BottomAppBar это проект на гитхабе может будет легче так

Comment: Легче следовать правилам данного сообщества. В частности - как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ

Comment: @pavloff Okey...